# Case Class Instantiation From Typesafe Config

Tags: scala, typesafe-config, hocon

Suppose I have a scala case class with the ability to serialize into json (using json4s or some other library):

```
case class Weather(zip : String, temp : Double, isRaining : Boolean)
```

If I'm using a [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) config file:

```
allWeather {

   BeverlyHills {
    zip : 90210
    temp : 75.0
    isRaining : false
  }

  Cambridge {
    zip : 10013
    temp : 32.0
    isRainging : true
  }

}
```

**Is there any way to use [typesafe config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) to automatically instantiate a `Weather` object?**

I'm looking for something of the form

```
val config : Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File("weather.conf"))

val bevHills : Weather = config.getObject("allWeather.BeverlyHills").as[Weather]
```

The solution could leverage the fact that the value referenced by `"allWeather.BeverlyHills"` is a json "blob".

I could obviously write my own parser:

```
def configToWeather(config : Config) = 
  Weather(config.getString("zip"), 
          config.getDouble("temp"), 
          config.getBoolean("isRaining"))

val bevHills = configToWeather(config.getConfig("allWeather.BeverlyHills"))
```

But that seems inelegant since any change to the Weather definition would also require a change to `configToWeather`.

Thank you in advance for your review and response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

typesafe config library has [API to instantiate](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#configbeanfactory) object from config that uses java bean convention. But as I understand case class does not follow those rules.

There are [several scala libraries](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#scala-wrappers-for-the-java-library) that wrap typesafe config and provide scala specific functionality that you are looking for.

For example using [pureconfig](https://github.com/melrief/pureconfig#example) reading config could look like

```
val weather:Try[Weather] = loadConfig[Weather]
```

where `Weather` is a case class for values in config

Comment: +1 for pureconfig. Been familiar with Spring Boot's excellent [configuration management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), pureconfig is the closes thing that I could find in Scala.

Comment: "I understand case class does not follow those rules.": It does not, but you can use scala annotations to allow it: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/beans/BeanProperty.html

Comment: It was not clear to me from the documentation, that it might be most often used to create `ConfigObjectSource` and pass it to your parser function to load as the case class; this way, unit test etc can provide different ways of getting this object (from file, url, string, or the classic stack `application.conf/reference.conf/systemProperties` approach)

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on Nazarii's answer, the following worked for me:

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

//The @BeanProperty and var are both necessary
case class Weather(@BeanProperty var zip : String,
                   @BeanProperty var temp : Double,
                   @BeanProperty var isRaining : Boolean) {

  //needed by configfactory to conform to java bean standard
  def this() = this("", 0.0, false)
}

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File("allWeather.conf"))

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigBeanFactory

val bevHills = 
  ConfigBeanFactory.create(config.getConfig("allWeather.BeverlyHills"), classOf[Weather])
```

Follow up: based on the comments below it may be the case that only Java Collections, and not Scala Collections, are viable options for the parameters of the case class (e.g. `Seq[T]` will not work).

Comment: Note that all three of the no-argument constructor, `@BeanPropery` and `var` are required to make this work. If you forget `var` you'll silently get an empty value (as assigned in the constructor) instead of the configured one.

Comment: Apparently this is not working if one of the member variables is a `Seq[T]`

Comment: Follow up to the comment above : You should only use Java collections

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution without external libraries, inspired from playframework [Configuration.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.8/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L422)

```
trait ConfigLoader[A] { self =>
  def load(config: Config, path: String = ""): A
  def map[B](f: A => B): ConfigLoader[B] = (config, path) => f(self.load(config, path))
}
object ConfigLoader {
  def apply[A](f: Config => String => A): ConfigLoader[A] = f(_)(_)
  implicit val stringLoader: ConfigLoader[String] = ConfigLoader(_.getString)
  implicit val booleanLoader: ConfigLoader[Boolean] = ConfigLoader(_.getBoolean)
  implicit val doubleLoader: ConfigLoader[Double] = ConfigLoader(_.getDouble)
}
object Implicits {
  implicit class ConfigOps(private val config: Config) extends AnyVal {
    def apply[A](path: String)(implicit loader: ConfigLoader[A]): A = loader.load(config, path)
  }
  implicit def configLoader[A](f: Config => A): ConfigLoader[A] = ConfigLoader(_.getConfig).map(f)
}
```

Usage:

```
import Implicits._

case class Weather(zip: String, temp: Double, isRaining: Boolean)
object Weather {
  implicit val loader: ConfigLoader[Weather] = (c: Config) => Weather(
    c("zip"), c("temp"), c("isRaining")
  )
}

val config: Config = ???
val bevHills: Weather = config("allWeather.BeverlyHills")
```

[Run the code in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/giabao/NDh3LSsUTOmrLbKOB6LORA)

Answer (score 1):

Another tried-and-tested solution is to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. You don't need to tag `@BeanProperty` to any of your  case class parameters but you will have to define a no-arg constructor.

```
case class Weather(zip : String, temp : Double, isRaining : Boolean) {
  def this() = this(null, 0, false)
}

val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val bevHills = mapper.convertValue(config.getObject("allWeather.BeverlyHills").unwrapped, classOf[Weather])
```

Comment: To me this is the most readable and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use circe.config with the code below. See https://github.com/circe/circe-config

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.config.syntax._

def configToWeather(conf: Config): Weather = {
  conf.as[Weather]("allWeather.BeverlyHills") match {
    case Right(c) => c
    case _ => throw new Exception("invalid configuration")
  }
}
```

Comment: we used this in our projects it works very well.

Answer (score -1):

Using config loader

```scala
implicit val configLoader: ConfigLoader[Weather] = (rootConfig: Config, path: String) => {

  val config = rootConfig.getConfig(path)

  Weather(
    config.getString("zip"),
    config.getDouble("temp"),
    config.getBoolean("isRaining")
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the offered answer.  However, within the question I clearly stated a preference to avoid this type of solution.